# ComboBox selectedIndexchange event does not fire

Tags: vb.net

My combobox that has 2 item. This box has a selecteindexchange event. How do I get this event to fire off again if the user chooses the same item the second time around?

Comment: it does not fire because it did not **change**.  Perhaps you could write some code to clear the first selection before "the second time around"?

Comment: Actually that's a good solution since you probably want them to be mindful of their selection.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in your case

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted

End Sub
```

At this point the `ComboBox` doesn't have a selected text so use `ComboBox1.SelectedItem` which is populated at this point.